# Log Parser: HAVING Wildcards

Tags: logparser

I have a log parser query that gets the top 200 uris, however I don't want any cs-uri-stem entries that have a dot (.) in them.

This is as close as I've come, but it seems like the wildcards are not acting as I expected:

```
"SELECT TOP 200 cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) AS Total INTO \Top200URIs_NoDots.csv 
FROM "\2015-01\U*.log" 
GROUP BY cs-uri-stem 
HAVING cs-uri-stem NOT LIKE '%.%'
ORDER BY Total DESC"
```

When I run this I get an Error:

```
... HAVING cs-uri-stem NOT LIKE ''...
Error: Syntax Error: <having-clause>: not a valid <expression>
```

Why is it ignoring the '%'s and everything between?

Comment: Is this in a batch file?  % must be escaped as %% in a batch file.

Comment: THAT'S IT. Make that an answer, and I'll give you credit! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HAVING` is for filtering group results using aggregate functions on the grouped data.  Filtering on the grouped data is more processing-intensive because the grouping must be completed first.  In this case, your query will be more optimally performed using a `WHERE` clause anyway.  Also, remember to use `%%` if this is in a batch file.  A single `%` denotes a batch variable and won't make it to the program's arguments.